# Flutter - Dynamic Vertical and Horizontal scrolling in page sections

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm trying to achieve this particular transition in flutter,
where the user initially scrolls vertically and when he reaches a particular section it starts to scroll horizontally, all of this he has to always scroll down.

I'm trying to add this feature on Flutter Web, but it would be cool if it could be added to a mobile app.

That's what I want to achieve:
[image]

Here a [forum](https://gsap.com/community/forums/topic/27916-dynamic-vertical-and-horizontal-scrolling-in-page-sections/) section on GSAP that talks about this.

Thanks for your help!